# Find out users browser and operating system

Tags: asp.net, browser, operating-system

Is there a way in ASP.Net to find out the browser and operating system of the user?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's called the UserAgent, see HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent IIRC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx

Note however, this CAN be spoofed and changed.

Comment: Thanks I did it this way Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")